# How to read bmp files in tensorflow?

Tags: image, tensorflow, loading, decode, bmp

I'm trying to read BMP files in TensorFlow in the following way:

```
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
filename, label = tf.decode_csv(value, [[''], [0]])

im = tf.decode_raw(tf.read_file(filename), tf.uint8)
```

The error is the following:

```
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] Input to reshape is a tensor with 44200 values, but the requested shape has 750000
       [[Node: batch_processing/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch_processing/Slice, batch_processing/Reshape/shape)]]
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] Input to reshape is a tensor with 33871 values, but the requested shape has 750000
       [[Node: batch_processing/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch_processing/Slice, batch_processing/Reshape/shape)]] 
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] Input to reshape is a tensor with 47566 values, but the requested shape has 750000     
       [[Node: batch_processing/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch_processing/Slice, batch_processing/Reshape/shape)]]
```

Why does the output of **tf.decode** change? How can I solve the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are all of your images the same size?  Otherwise you'll get different size tensors when you decode them.

Comment: All images have the same size (500 x 500 x 3 = 750000), so I expected tensors with the same size

Comment: The other problem is you have an error with reshape but we don't see the code that actually calls it or the code before it making it a little hard to help.  Otherwise I can only speculate as to what the issue is.

Comment: I also think there may be a misconception in your question. If you really do have BMP image files, these aren't supported by TensorFlow. Instead, decode_raw attempts to load them as vectors of raw bytes, rather than decoding them, which may explain your error.

Comment: @PeteWarden, I know that Tensorflow supports only jpg, png and raw bytes images, but I did as suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/428). Anyway, I worked around by reading the original images as numpy arrays and by converting them in TFRecords. Thanks for your help!