# In Tensorflow, how can I deal with bmp files in a similar way as decode_png or decode_jpeg does?

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow

I am working on DL problems with tensorflow. My dataset is in BMP format, but all the sample code I've found playing with 'decode_png' or 'decode_jpeg'. I supposed there should be a similar API for BMP files, while just end up with nothing found.

What should I do if I want to process my BMP data in a similar way as 'decode_png' or 'decode_jpg' does?

Comment: Take a look at the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604530/how-to-read-bmp-files-in-tensorflow). Since officially bitmap is not supported by tensorflow, you might want to read the data as numpy array and then convert to `TFrecord`s

Comment: Thank you for your precious comment. It seems that 'decode_bmp' has been added in [the newest master branch](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_bmp). While I still need to convert the bmp data manually currently.